# Angular2 RC5 Importing 3rd Party JS Library: Showdown

Tags: javascript, angular, showdown

I'm having trouble importing [Showdown](https://github.com/showdownjs/showdown) as a vendor. When I compile, I get `showdown is not defined` in the browser console. Since it is a vendor package, I don't think I can import it inside of `app.module.ts`. Do I need to declare a custom typing for it? The package is all in `js`. I am running on Angular2 RC5. Thanks!

home.service.ts

```
import 'showdown/dist/showdown';

declare var showdown: any;

private extractData(res: Response) {
   let body      = res.json();
   var converter = new showdown.Converter(),
   originalBody  = window.atob(body.content),
   body.title    = converter.makeHtml(title);
}
```

vendor.browser.ts

```
import 'showdown/dist/showdown';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to employ typings mentioned by Yakov Fain

```
import {Converter} from "showdown/dist/showdown";

const converter = new Converter();
var body.title = converter.makeHtml(title);
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm not familiar with the Showdown, but if you want to import it in the code you need to have type definition files. If you use TypeScript 2.0, you can simply install it from npmjs.org. I just checked - they have the type definitions for Showdown in the @types organization: https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=%40types%2Fshowdown

Just run `npm i @types/showdown --save-dev`.

If you use older TypeScript, install the declarations with Typings. 
Don't forget to add a script tag for Showdown in your index.html.

In this sample app I use JQuery implicitely, but don't need to import it though:

https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/tree/master/chapter2/auction

Comment: Thank you for responding! I am using TypeScript 2.0 and installed the type definition. I'm using webpack to load all my bundles and Showdown is getting passed through the vendor bundle. Still doesn't want to load though...

Comment: Then see this code sample that uses jQuery and Webpack:
https://github.com/Farata/angular2typescript/tree/master/chapter10/auction

Comment: Apologies, I figured out how to employ the Showdown typings and it worked!